# Using MFMailComposeViewController with UTF-8 domains and/or usernames

Tags: ios, email, utf-8

I'm trying to prepopulate the MFMailComposeViewController with an email address that has a UTF-8 domain (e.g. hello@闪闪发光.com ). However, when I call setToRecepients on my object, I get a message in the console that 'hello@闪闪发光.com is not a valid email address and the email controller comes up with an empty To field. If I use the same email address and just type it in directly, I get a warning that it is not a valid email address, but I am given the option to send anyway.

Is this just something not supported? UTF-8 domain may not be too common but they're definitely out there. I tried to encode the value with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding but that didn't do it.

Any thoughts? Anybody run into this before? Workarounds?

I also just tried this in the latest 6.0 SDK using Apple's sample code with only the To address changed to UTF-8, same result.

I posted this on the Apple dev forums but I usually get a better response here so I'm trying here too.

Comment: That is not compatible with [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) which is most widely implemented

Answer (score 0):

You can try using NSUTF16StringEncoding instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding. Further you can refer the [different types of encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding)

Comment: I ended up kicking it up to product management and getting the requirement removed.